# Create object from array with strict ordering like inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this :

```
var startArray = [
{value: 2, label: 'label 2'},
{value: 1, label: 'label 1'},
{value: 17, label: 'label 17'},
{value: 15, label: 'label 15'}
];
```

And i want create the object like this:

```
var middleObject = {
2: 'label 2',
1: 'label 1',
17: 'label 17',
15: 'label 15'
};
```

And i used the code:

```
startArray.forEach( function(oneOption) {
  middleObject[oneOption.value] = oneOption.label;
});
enter code here
```

I also was tried to use this code (with the same result):

```
for (var oneOption in startArray) {
  middleObject[oneOption.value] = oneOption.label;
}
```

But problem is when i use this code i take the object like this:

```
var middleWrongObject = {
1: 'label 1',
2: 'label 2',
15: 'label 15',
17: 'label 17'
};
```

but some later i should used `middleObject` in the loop with the same ordering like at the `firstArray`. And property inside `middleObject` every time should be the number type. Do we have some method to set ordering for property inside the `middleObject`(without set property "ordering" and sort by this field later)
Thanks for the help.

Comment: why not use an array instead of an object which has actually no order?

Comment: Object properties have no order

Comment: Further to the above comment - see this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Because `middleObject` create from many way one of them take it from `firstArray` and any ways don't have this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the given array in a part for sorted keys and use an object as reference to the data.

```js
var startArray = [{ value: 2, label: 'label 2' }, { value: 1, label: 'label 1' }, { value: 17, label: 'label 17' }, { value: 15, label: 'label 15' }],
    keys = startArray.map(a => a.value),
    object = Object.assign(...startArray.map(a => ({ [a.value]: a.label })));
    
keys.sort((a, b) => a - b);             // keys in asc order

console.log(keys.map(k => object[k]));  // access via keys
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Yes it was helpful but without sorting a keys, because sorting breaks my conception reproduce the ordering of startArray